# Javascript Keydown event is triggered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm handling a keydown event on the document so that I can `undo` when `ctrl + z` is pressed.

This is how I'm binding it with my document:

```
componentWillMount() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', throttle(this.handleKeyDown, 300));
}

handleKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.which === KEY_Z) {
    console.log('Undo');
  }
}
```

But whenever the keys are pressed, the event is triggered twice which means it undoes two states at a time. As you can see I've also tried to throttle the event using `lodash`, but there is no effect.

Comment: Your title says `keydown` but you're listening for `keyup`.

Comment: Why throttle a key event? Then, are the two callback calls fired with the same event? Because if you are listening for ctrl + Z, then you'll have the one of ctrl and the one of Z.

Comment: My bad I changed it at the last minute to test. It's keydown I'll update.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, I get two console logs when pressed in the above case.

Comment: And if you add a console.log('adding handler') in `componentWillMount`, what do you see? If it's logged only once, then try `throttle(()=>{console.log("throttle")}, 300)()`.

Comment: Both cases, It is logged only once, but if I log within the `handleKeyDown` it gets logged twice.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get one event for the keycombination rather, an event is triggered for each key pressed. The ctrl key will fire the event by itself before the z key is pressed.

Comment: Is there any solution to this behaviour?

Comment: One way is to remember the state of keys like Ctrl, Alt, Shift etc.   using both keyDown and keyUp event handlers. i.e. set ctrKeyPressed to true on the keyDown event (when e.ctrlKey is true) and set it back to false on the keyUp event (again when e.ctrlKey is true.) Then combine that state information during the event processing of the z key.